# Mysql query to Remove similar looking column rows without data loss in 2nd table

Tags: mysql, database

I have 2 tables : `companies` and `company_details`. where `company_details` is connected by `companies` table with `companyID`. I want to remove similar looking company name and keep the lowest id value in `company` table and also update the `companyId` in the 2nd table.

Is this possible to do ? Is there any MYSQL Query that can achieve this ?

My Original Table :

```
1st Table: Companies
----------------------
id  |   name        |
----------------------
10  |   Ions Comps  |
11  |   Ions Comp's |   
12  |   Ion Comp    |   
13  |   Lamar corp  |
14  |   Lamar       |

2nd Table: Company_details
--------------------------------
id  | companyID  |  city       |
--------------------------------
1   |   10       |  Alabama    |
2   |   11       |  California |
3   |   12       |  LA         |    
4   |   13       |  Ohio       |    
5   |   14       |  West       |
```

I want my table to be like this:

```
1st Table: Companies
------------------------
id  |   name        |   
------------------------
10  |   Ions Comps  |   
13  |   Lamar corp  |   

2nd Table: Company_details
--------------------------------
id  | companyID  |  city       |    
--------------------------------
1   |   10       |  Alabama    |    
2   |   10       |  California |    
3   |   10       |  LA         |    
4   |   13       |  Ohio       |    
5   |   13       |  West       |
```

Comment: How can the query knows which is right `Ions Comps`, `Ions Comp's` or `Ion Comp`, what are the conditions for the query to choose the right one ?

Comment: Is the id auto_increment on `Companies` table ?

Comment: It would seem the created and updated columns are irrelevant (so why include them?) and you neglect to specify the logic to select which row to keep, which *appears* to be the lowest id value?

Comment: @ErgestBasha Yes id auto_increment on Companies table.
Also we can just leave the name which is having minimum ID. rest we need to remove

Comment: @Stu Yes created_at and updated_at are irrelavant. I just need to keep the lowest id value from the similar ones as you said. I added this in the query now

Comment: But what if you have `Len's Comps` and `Ken's Comps`? Are you only considering variations at the end of the string?

Comment: I suggest using `SOUNDEX()` to find the similar names.

Comment: @CaiusJard I changed the name of those companies. Please take a look at the query now

Comment: In order to update `company_details`, you shold create a temporary table that lists the IDs being removed and the main company ID that replaces it. Use that to update the foreign key.

Comment: How perfect do you want it to be? I'm thinking, essentially, that you start with some low numbered company and then work out the Levenshtein distance from that co name to every other co name in the db, take all those less than a certain distance and collapse them into one co, remove them from the set, then repeat with the next lowest numbered co vs all remainders. The problem you have is that, in essence, it's "easy" for your brain to say "oh, those 3 companies are clearly the same because they follow similar patterns" but the human brain *is a pattern matching device*..

Comment: Short of training some ML/NLP solution up to read your names, any algorithm that does wht you want should definitely operate with oversight, rather than a "hey, just copy this update query off SO, run it and it will fix everything"